# Azure Webjob created in Visual Studio 2015 fails to run

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs

An Azure Webjob created in Visual Studio 2015 (any job, including the sample project) fails to run in an azure website with the following error:

Job failed due to exit code -2146232576

Note: the same project created in Visual Studio 2013 deploys and runs successfully.

How can I fix the project in VS2015?

Comment: Any obvious differences between the 2 webjobs?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? AFAIK .NET 4.6 is not supported on azure web sites yet.

Comment: Can you share steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The problem is indeed .Net framework version. The same project compiled with 4.5 runs successfully, and if compiled with 4.5.3 fails.

Fabrizio, if you add your comment as an answer I will vote it up

Answer (score 2):

Which version of .NET are you using? AFAIK .NET 4.6 is not supported on azure web sites yet.

Answer (score 2):

Found a work around for publishing vNext WebJob [Issue #338](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/338).

Here are the steps:

1. Create vNext Console App
2. Add `"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs": "1.0.1"` to `packages.json`, or whichever the latest WJ package.
3. Go to console (make sure you have DNU installed), navigate to Console App and run this command: `dnu publish --runtime active` (or whatever runtime you want to use)
4. Zip the content of `/bin/output` folder and upload it via azure dashboard.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It says "Pending Restart" with .net 4.6 version. Do you know there is no support yet? I am taking "warning MSB3277".